# How to add a unique constraint for a label in a Neo4J database using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to create a Unique Constraint of a Node's property in Kotlin or Java Spring.

How do I trigger or set up a constraint equivalent to this cypher
query:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT constraint_name IF NOT EXISTS FOR (book:Book) REQUIRE book.isbn IS UNIQUE
```

Comment: In the last version of spring-data-neo4j you should be able in creating unique index by using the OGM Library. Check spring reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference section Automatic creation of constraints and indexes

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data Neo4j 6+ does not allow the creation of constraints and indexes anymore. We are convinced that database related schema operations should not be in the responsible of an object [graph/something] mapper.
To fill this gap, we created [Neo4j-Migrations](https://michael-simons.github.io/neo4j-migrations/current/). It does not even provide more functionality but also helps to keep the concerns of DBA operations and mapping separated.

Comment: Interesting, but I'm flagging a field as Id annotated in my Node annotated class, and still an Id is being created by Neo4J and I get duplicates, even if my property flagged as Id has the same value, Node4J is creating another Id that is different (e.g incremental).

Comment: Could you raise another question with more details (like model etc.) regarding this?